# Problems using $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I'm calling the following URL using YQL

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22UTG.L%22)%0A%09%09&format=json&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=cbfunc
```

this returns the following in JSON

```
cbfunc({"query":{"count":"1","created":"2009-06-27T11:53:44Z","lang":"en-US","updated":"2009-06-27T11:53:44Z","uri":"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?q=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.quotes+where+symbol+in+%28%22UTG.L%22%29","diagnostics":{"publiclyCallable":"true","url":[{"execution-time":"468","content":"http://datatables.org/alltables.env"},{"execution-time":"634","content":"http://www.datatables.org/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.quotes.xml"},{"execution-time":"351","content":"http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=UTG.L&f=aa2bb2b3b4cc1c3c6c8dd1d2ee1e7e8e9ghjkg1g3g4g5g6ii5j1j3j4j5j6k1k2k4k5ll1l2l3mm2m3m4m5m6m7m8nn4opp1p2p5p6qrr1r2r5r6r7ss1s7t1t7t8vv1v7ww1w4xy"},{"execution-time":"357","content":"select * from csv where url=@url and columns='Ask,AverageDailyVolume,Bid,AskRealtime,BidRealtime,BookValue,Change&PercentChange,Change,Commission,ChangeRealtime,AfterHoursChangeRealtime,DividendShare,LastTradeDate,TradeDate,EarningsShare,ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid,EPSEstimateCurrentYear,EPSEstimateNextYear,EPSEstimateNextQuarter,DaysLow,DaysHigh,YearLow,YearHigh,HoldingsGainPercent,AnnualizedGain,HoldingsGain,HoldingsGainPercentRealtime,HoldingsGainRealtime,MoreInfo,OrderBookRealtime,MarketCapitalization,MarketCapRealtime,EBITDA,ChangeFromYearLow,PercentChangeFromYearLow,LastTradeRealtimeWithTime,ChangePercentRealtime,ChangeFromYearHigh,PercebtChangeFromYearHigh,LastTradeWithTime,LastTradePriceOnly,HighLimit,LowLimit,DaysRange,DaysRangeRealtime,FiftydayMovingAverage,TwoHundreddayMovingAverage,ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage,PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage,ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage,PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage,Name,Notes,Open,PreviousClose,PricePaid,ChangeinPercent,PriceSales,PriceBook,ExDividendDate,PERatio,DividendPayDate,PERatioRealtime,PEGRatio,PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear,PriceEPSEstimateNextYear,Symbol,SharesOwned,ShortRatio,LastTradeTime,TickerTrend,OneyrTargetPrice,Volume,HoldingsValue,HoldingsValueRealtime,YearRange,DaysValueChange,DaysValueChangeRealtime,StockExchange,DividendYield'"}],"javascript":{"instructions-used":"66024"},"user-time":"1537","service-time":"1810","build-version":"1949"},"results":{"quote":{"symbol":"UTG.L","Ask":"129.00","AverageDailyVolume":"354500","Bid":"128.50","AskRealtime":"129.00","BidRealtime":"128.50","BookValue":"0.00","Change_PercentChange":"+7.50 - +6.19%","Change":"+7.50","Commission":null,"ChangeRealtime":"+7.50","AfterHoursChangeRealtime":"N/A - N/A","DividendShare":"0.00","LastTradeDate":"6/26/2009","TradeDate":null,"EarningsShare":"0.00","ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid":"N/A","EPSEstimateCurrentYear":"0.00","EPSEstimateNextYear":"0.00","EPSEstimateNextQuarter":"0.00","DaysLow":"122.00","DaysHigh":"128.75","YearLow":"36.25","YearHigh":"319.75","HoldingsGainPercent":"- - -","AnnualizedGain":"-","HoldingsGain":null,"HoldingsGainPercentRealtime":"N/A - N/A","HoldingsGainRealtime":null,"MoreInfo":"cred","OrderBookRealtime":"N/A","MarketCapitalization":null,"MarketCapRealtime":null,"EBITDA":"0","ChangeFromYearLow":"+92.50","PercentChangeFromYearLow":"+255.17%","LastTradeRealtimeWithTime":"N/A - <b>128.75<\/b>","ChangePercentRealtime":"N/A - +6.19%","ChangeFromYearHigh":"-191.00","PercebtChangeFromYearHigh":"-59.73%","LastTradeWithTime":"Jun 26 - <b>128.75<\/b>","LastTradePriceOnly":"128.75","HighLimit":null,"LowLimit":null,"DaysRange":"122.00 - 128.75","DaysRangeRealtime":"N/A - N/A","FiftydayMovingAverage":"125.714","TwoHundreddayMovingAverage":"100.63","ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage":"+28.12","PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage":"+27.94%","ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage":"+3.036","PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage":"+2.42%","Name":"UNITE GROUP","Notes":"-","Open":"122.00","PreviousClose":"121.25","PricePaid":null,"ChangeinPercent":"+6.19%","PriceSales":null,"PriceBook":null,"ExDividendDate":"14-Apr-04","PERatio":null,"DividendPayDate":"13-May-05","PERatioRealtime":null,"PEGRatio":null,"PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear":null,"PriceEPSEstimateNextYear":null,"Symbol":"UTG.L","SharesOwned":null,"ShortRatio":null,"LastTradeTime":"11:35am","TickerTrend":"&nbsp;--=+++&nbsp;","OneyrTargetPrice":null,"Volume":"254927","HoldingsValue":null,"HoldingsValueRealtime":null,"YearRange":"36.25 - 319.75","DaysValueChange":"- - +6.19%","DaysValueChangeRealtime":"N/A - N/A","StockExchange":"London","DividendYield":null,"PercentChange":"+6.19%"}}}});
```

But I'm struggling to use the data (I'm a newbie with jQuery and JSON) using

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22UTG.L%22)%0A%09%09&format=json&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=cbfunc",
    function(data){
```

from [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) example just flashes a restricted URL error.

Anybody help - I simply was to parse the data and print to screen. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll have to replace your callback parameter (currently `cbfunc`) in the URL with `?`. jQuery will automatically replace the `?` with a correct callback.

```
$.getJSON(
  "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22UTG.L%22)%0A%09%09&format=json&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=?", // the ? at the end is the key
  function(data) {
    // and now do anything you want to with the data (this is just an example)
    var html = []; // we're using an array and join for IE performance reasons
    data = data.query;
    for (var key in data) {
      html.push([key, ' = ', data[key]].join(''));
    }
    $('#debug').html(html.join('<br />'));
  }
);
```

**Update**: Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/owebo

Comment: Moff, I added the following to handle the data:-

$.each(data.query.results.row, function(index, item){
    $('#quotes')
    .append(
      $('<p/>')
        .append($('<span class="left"/>').text(item.symbol))
        .append($('<span class="right"/>').text('$'+item.price))
      );
    });

but I get 'g is undefined' coming back in Firebug, any thoughts?

Comment: I tried your code and it turns out that data.query.results.row isn't defined (though data.query.results is.) If you want to check the returned object properties, add console.log(data) to your callback function. Then, check the Firebug console (download at <http://getfirebug.com/>) for Firefox or the Safari Web Inspector (included in Safari 3 and later, I think).